# Qual è il senso di "ci siamo fatte belle" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, meaning, plural

Nel romanzo *La ragazza di Bube* di Carlo Cassola ho letto:

> Il giovanotto entrò nel bagno: fischiettava. Lei intanto si vestì. Quello dovette sentir rumore, perché tornò sul pianerottolo: «Sei tu, Mara? Credevo che fossi uscita». Mara finalmente venne fuori; il giovanotto era sempre lì, e commentò: «Oh! come **ci siamo fatte belle**». Mara tirò di lungo, e il giovanotto le gridò dietro: «Giacché ci sei, preparami il tè».

Non capisco del tutto bene il senso dell'espressione "ci siamo fatte belle" in questo brano. Significa che il giovanotto vuol dire a Mara che si è fatta bella? Se è così, perché usa la prima persona plurale invece della seconda persona singolare? Se non è così, potresti spiegarmi qual è il significato della frase?

Potresti farmi alcuni altri esempi di questo uso della prima persona plurale del verbo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

L'esclamazione vuol proprio dire che Mara si è fatta bella nel senso che si è vestita in modo elegante, si è truccata, si è pettinata con particolare cura. L'uso della prima persona plurale quando ci si rivolge a una persona sola non è raro ed è un modo per non parlare direttamente a quella persona, perché le si sta facendo un complimento, o si fanno considerazioni personali oppure la si vuole rimproverare, o si usa un tono paternalistico. Si può dire, ad esempio, incontrando un bambino che non si vedeva da tempo: «Ma come siamo diventati grandi!». Oppure, un medico può accogliere un paziente chiedendo: «Come stiamo oggi?».

Comment: Giusto, e aggiungo che questo modo di esprimersi può a volte esprimere una punta di paternalismo, come appunto nell'esempio del bambino, o quando un medico chiede a un paziente: «Come stiamo oggi?»

Comment: @DaG che dici, aggiungiamo l'esempio alla risposta?

Comment: Io penso che sia una buona idea aggiungerlo.

Comment: Ho fatto le aggiunte, integrando nella risposta il commento di @DaG. Possono andare bene?

Comment: Per quanto mi riguarda, perfetto, grazie.

Comment: Prego, @DaG! (vale anche per un'altra occasione, in cui non ho potuto rispondere perché i caratteri erano troppo pochi) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Aggiungerei alla risposta di Benedetta che il plurale include la persona che sta parlando, come se fosse lei stessa coinvolta dall'affermazione.

Non ho trovato fonti a supporto, ma direi che è usato per "mettersi sullo stesso piano" della persona a cui si parla, appunto in senso paternalistico, come farebbe un genitore col figlio.